# Error on sql oracle PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Tags: sql, oracle

This SQL code is giving me the error "Error at line 2: PL/SQL: Statement ignored ", Im working on SQL oracle application express / APEX: I tried everything I can think of and it gives me different problems everytime.

```
CREATE or replace TRIGGER remove_artista 
   instead of delete on V_ARTISTA
REFERENCING old AS orow
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
if exists(select * from Utilizadores where pessoaID = orow.pessoaID) then
        delete from Pessoas where pessoaID = orow.pessoaID;
ELSE
        delete from Artistas where pessoaID = orow.pessoaID;
        delete from Pessoas where pessoaID = orow.pessoaID;
end if;
END;
```

The view:

```
create or replace view v_artista as 
 select 
pessoaID, nome_p, sexo, data_nasc, nome_art, biografica
from Pessoas natural inner join Artistas;
```

EDIT: fixed a litle typo on the code.

Comment: I'm assuming your view `V_ARTISTA` is not updatable for delete statement which is why it's giving error on line 2. Can you verify the same by querying `USER_UPDATABLE_COLUMNS`?

Comment: @Ravi. you want me to run the query "USER_UPDATABLE_COLUMNS" sorry noob here

Comment: @Ravi. added the code for the view

Comment: Please verify wether the column_name `essoaID` have delete rights as `YES` by querying `SELECT * FROM USER_UPDATABLE_COLUMNS`

Comment: @Ravi. It has yes in the column deletable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full error I receive from your trigger is as follows:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/1      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
2/4      PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'EXISTS' may be used inside
         a SQL statement only
```

Essentially, the problem is that you can't say `if exists(...)` as you are doing.  Oracle doesn't let you.

Instead, try selecting the number of matching rows in the `Utilizadores` table into a local variable, and then using that in your `if` statement:

```
CREATE or replace TRIGGER remove_artista 
   instead of delete on V_ARTISTA
REFERENCING old AS orow
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  l_count       INTEGER;
BEGIN
  select count(*) 
    into l_count
    from Utilizadores
   where pessoaID = :orow.pessoaID;

  if l_count > 0 then
        delete from Pessoas where pessoaID = :orow.pessoaID;
  ELSE
        delete from Artistas where pessoaID = :orow.pessoaID;
        delete from Pessoas where pessoaID = :orow.pessoaID;
  end if;
END;
```

I also needed to replace `orow` with `:orow`.  After making this change as well, your trigger compiled for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use the IF EXISTS construct to check if a row exists. You can use `SELECT COUNT(*) INTO <a variable>`. However, you may not need to check if a row exists. The following code would probably work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER remove_artista 
INSTEAD OF DELETE ON V_ARTISTA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM PESSOAS
  WHERE PESSOAID = :OLD.PESSOAID;

  DELETE FROM Artistas
  WHERE PESSOAID = :OLD.PESSOAID
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UTILIZADORES WHERE PESSOAID = :OLD.PESSOAID);  

END;
```

The row from `PESSOAS` would be deleted in any case. The row from `ARTISTAS` would be deleted only if the `PESSOAID` does not exist in `UTILIZADORES`.

**References**:

[Check if record exists on OTN forum](https://community.oracle.com/thread/831953?start=0&tstart=0)